# Show loading bar for every http request angular2

Tags: angular, progress-bar, loading, angular-http-interceptors

I am moving my app from angularjs to angular2. I was using `Angular Loading Bar` which is

> An automatic loading bar using angular interceptors. It works
>   automatically, so simply include it as a dependency and it will
>   automatically display the progress of your $http requests.

[More info](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation#)

I am trying to find similar plugin in angular2. I came across a few like `ng2-slim-loading-bar` but here I have to manually manage the progress. For every http request, I have to manually start the progress bar and then finish it.

So, are there any existing plugin available which can do exactly what `Angular Loading Bar` does in angularjs. Or how can I modify any existing plugin to behave like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [ngx-progressbar](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar). It can [automatically](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar#user-content-automagic-loading-bar) show the progress bar while a HTTP request is running.

All you have to do is :

1- Import and provide `NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr`

```
import { NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr } from 'ngx-progressbar';

@NgModule({
 providers: [
   // ...
   { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr } ,
 ],
 imports: [
   // ...
   NgProgressModule
 ]
})
```

2- Use it like below in your template.

```
<ng-progress></ng-progress>
```

> The progress will start and complete automatically with your HTTP
>   requests. no need to use NgProgressService to call start()/done()
>   manually.

Comment: I am getting error.. can not find name NgProgressModule

I am using angular-cli for my app.. I have installed the package and added this under script tag under angular-cli.json . Am i missing anything?

Comment: I have fixed previous issue.. now getting this error: I am getting error.. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined

Not sure where I am missing.

Comment: (addScript.js:9),

Comment: even though progess baar shows.. I see previous mentioned error.. I will try to debug it

Comment: You can, the progress bar will be displayed in all your pages

Comment: Remove the script you added in angular-cli.json

Comment: you are awesome.. you exactly found that issue.. I remvoed that and it worked

Comment: Hi @Radounane , can you please check this question, related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996803/cant-bind-to-thick-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-progress

Comment: This is so cool. But is there a way to show the progress corresponding to the size of downloaded content at any given point of time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did in our project (Red Hat Automated Migration Toolkit):

- In our HTTP service wrapper (handling OAuth), we fire an event,
- which is then caught by our `LoadingIndicatorService`.
- `LoadingIndicatorService`

  - wraps the `SlimLoaderBarService`,
  - and keeps track of how many HTTP requests there are in progress.
  - Then it counts the percent and puts it to a scale of 20 to 90 %.
  - When all HTTP requests are done, it stays at 90 % for about a second, and then `complete()` is called.

If you have multiple requests for each navigation step, this looks quite naturally and provides a good UX.
If you typically only have 1 request, then you might want to either adjust the CSS based animation (make it longer) or use `start()` afterall.

Here are some key code parts:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingIndicatorService {

    constructor(
        private _slimBarService: SlimLoadingBarService,
        private _eventBusService: EventBusService,
    ) {
        // Register the LoadingSomething event listeners.
        this._eventBusService.onEvent
            .filter(event => event.isTypeOf(LoadingSomethingStartedEvent))
            .subscribe((event: LoadingSomethingStartedEvent) => this.loadingStarted() )
        this._eventBusService.onEvent
            .filter(event => event.isTypeOf(LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent))
            .subscribe((event: LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent) => this.loadingFinished() )
    }

    public getSlimService(){
        return this._slimBarService;
    }


    private counter: number = 0;
    private max: number = void 0;

    private reset() {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.max = void 0;
    }

    public loadingStarted(){
        this.counter++;
        this.max = this.counter;
        this.updateProgress();
    }

    public loadingFinished(){
        this.counter--;
        this.updateProgress();
    }

    private updateProgress() {
        if (this.counter == 0) {
            this._slimBarService.height = "2px";
            this._slimBarService.visible = true;
            this._slimBarService.progress = 95;
            this.max = void 0;
            Observable.timer(700).subscribe(() => {
                this._slimBarService.complete();
            });
        }
        else {
            // max - counter = finished.
            // If the things to load are added after something loaded, the progress would go back.
            // But let's rely on that loading will start fast at the beginning.
            // Start at 20, jump to 90.
            let percent = 20 + 70 * (1 - (this.max - this.counter) / this.max);
            this._slimBarService.height = "3px";
            this._slimBarService.color = "#39a5dc";
            this._slimBarService.visible = true;
            this._slimBarService.progress = percent;
        }
    }

}


    let responseObservable2 = responseObservable.do(
        () => console.log("Request SUCCEEDED"),
        () => console.log("Request FAILED"),
        () => {
            console.log("Request FINISHED");
            if (this._eventBus) {
                console.log("Request FINISHED, firing");
                this._eventBus.fireEvent(new LoadingSomethingFinishedEvent(responseObservable))
            }
        }
    );
```

HTTP service wrapper:

```
@Injectable()
export class WindupHttpService extends Http {

    private configureRequest(method: RequestMethod, f: Function, url: string | Request, options: RequestOptionsArgs = {}, body?: any): Observable<Response> {
        let responseObservable: Observable<Response> = ...

    ...

    console.log("Load STARTED");
    if (this._eventBus)
        console.log("Load STARTED, firing");
    this._eventBus.fireEvent(new LoadingSomethingStartedEvent(responseObservable));

    return responseObservable2;
}
```

For the complete code, search github.com for project Windup.

Answer (score 1):

check `@ngx-loading-bar` which automatically will add progress bar for Http calls and routings

https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar