# Can't bind to 'thick' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-progress'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-components

> I am trying to use this plugin to my app:
>   https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar#user-content-automagic-loading-bar

Its working fine, but when I run test on it, it fails with error:

Can't bind to 'thick' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-progress'.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr, NgProgressModule } from 'ngx-progressbar';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      NgProgressModule
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My app.component.html

```
<ng-progress [thick]="'true'" [showSpinner]="'false'"></ng-progress>
```

When I run 
npm run test

it fails with error:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>       1. If 'ng-progress' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

I am completely clueless why Test is only failing.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding your test configuration

Comment: can you provide your spec file ? it's seems that you forgot to provide your component in your test.

Comment: My bad.. this is what happens when you are in hurry.. Thanks @runit . You pointed right. If you can add this comment as answer, I can accept that and may help some users like me.

Comment: Can you still provide your spec file? I have the same problem and would be handy to see how you fixed it. Thanks

Comment: could you please put your spec file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, you forget to provide your component in your test.